# Checking apple touch icon

Tags: html, apple-touch-icon

I've just set up an apple touch icon link and image for a website and I'd like to check whether or not it works. Without an iDevice I'm struggling to perform this test.

Does anyone know of a tool that can be used to perform this test?

Comment: Does it help you? http://mobiletest.me/

Comment: `Does anyone know of a tool that can be used to perform this test?` Asking for a tool is off topic here.

Comment: @GabrielMoretti Useful tool but doesn't address what we're trying to do. Thanks though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can give a try to http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this tool.

Comment: That's quite useful but I don't get to see the actual images that have been specified. Also I'm guessing under desktop, android, ios, and windows 8, I'm mean to get a result of success, warning, or danger. I get nothing its all there but hidden in css.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment, sorry. What does the favicon checker says? Do you see your apple touch icon? Another picture? Nothing? Or the checker fails?

Comment: Oh. So now I'm the guy with the question and you're the guy with the answer: could you give me the URL of your site so I can review it? :) (if you prefer, mail it to me, look for the "contact" link on the site)

Comment: I've checked a handful of other sites using your checker and they seem to work. I think that the issue is that your tool probably doesn't follow any redirects. While our domain is example.com, that redirects to example.com/home and your tool seems to have a bit of a brain freeze with that. If I plug in example.com/home, then I get the desired output which is exactly what I was after.

Comment: Redirections... alright, I need to check this. Thanks for reporting and glad it's a valuable answer to your own question!