# iOS apple-touch-icon works only on one URL

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I have a single-page Progressive Web App (accessed from iPhones), and I've added the following to my `<head>`:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/appicon/acme_homescreen_60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/appicon/acme_homescreen_120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/appicon/acme_homescreen_152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="img/appicon/acme_homescreen_167x167.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/appicon/acme_homescreen_180x180.png">
```

This works on https://acme.com/login, so there's no basic problem such as misspelled file name, wrong path, password protection, ... Yet it doesn't work on https://acme.com/selection nor any other URL besides /login. I get the default screenshot there.

I double checked: There's the same `<head>` on all URLs, so what am I missing?

PS: I cannot use https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30096615/3890673), as the server is running locally.

Comment: https://acme.com/login and https://acme.com/selection are 404. Is this normal ? Anyway, `img/appicon/acme_homescreen_120x120.png` seems to be relative path, is it possible that you error come from here ?

Comment: Acme [is fictional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation), but no, the relative path is the same from both URLs. It seems to be kind of  a bug, see my answer: While it works for one URL it has to be in the root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still not understand why it's working on /login, the solution seems to be to put an (additional) `apple-touch-icon.png` **in the root directory**. In order to have all icons in one place I moved all the referenced icons to the root, but it seems to be sufficient to have `apple-touch-icon.png` there.

To use the root directory is mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4), to be fair.